# Android Method to run on activity start and not onCreate

Tags: android, methods, android-activity, oncreate

I have a method that I need to run when the activity starts.
I've tried putting it in the OnCreate but the onCreate is called twice if the activity is left untouched for a while (and that's the case, i'm checking for online updates... so it takes some time)

that's why i can't put the update method in the onCreate

any ideas?

Thank you,
Ron

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.options);
    checkUpdate();
}

private void checkUpdate(){
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try
            {
                // create a web request to check if i have the latest update
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
.
.
.
.
.
        };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Comment: Is your activity still executing and onCreate gets called again?  I didn't think that was possible, unless you rotated the device?

Comment: the device is not rotating, maybe it's because the screen is getting darker? but i'm not touching it and the onCreate method is called again.

Comment: It might help to see the bare bones code of your activity.  Possibly you should put your update check into an AsyncTask as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a boolean to determine if the activity is already started.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you don't want to put methods that take some time to execute on the UI Thread. 
Instead, you may want to create AsyncTask (or Thread/Handlers) to run the method in the background. Also see if onStart() will help you move around some logic away from onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

you can execute that method in oncreate but add a class boolean field to check if you already add run that method.